# Minecraft Could not find or load main class -Dminecraft.launcher.version=2.6.16

Tags: java, godot, minecraft-forge, jvm-arguments

I'm making a minecraft launcher in godot 4 and for some reason, I get this error in the console. (I pasted the arguments directly from Process Explorer)

I have tried searching for this problem but couldn't find any answers.

I Tested it with these java versions:  jdk-16,jre-1.8 (I was trying to launch Minecraft 1.16.5 with forge)

If this answer is not clear enough or if you need some additional resources that I have not listed in my question then feel free to ask in the comments

Minecraft Arguments

```
XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump "-Dos.name=Windows 10" -Dos.version=10.0 -Xss1M -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\aa3ff1ab4ceab9fa81e22cec28be461e9bc33e34 -Dminecraft.launcher.brand=minecraft-launcher -Dminecraft.launcher.version=2.6.16 -cp C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\forge\1.16.5-36.2.39\forge-1.16.5-36.2.39.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm\9.1\asm-9.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-commons\9.1\asm-commons-9.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-tree\9.1\asm-tree-9.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-util\9.1\asm-util-9.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-analysis\9.1\asm-analysis-9.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\cpw\mods\modlauncher\8.1.3\modlauncher-8.1.3.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\cpw\mods\grossjava9hacks\1.3.3\grossjava9hacks-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\accesstransformers\3.0.1\accesstransformers-3.0.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.9.1\antlr4-runtime-4.9.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\eventbus\4.0.0\eventbus-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\forgespi\3.2.0\forgespi-3.2.0.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\coremods\4.0.6\coremods-4.0.6.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\unsafe\0.2.0\unsafe-0.2.0.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\electronwill\night-config\core\3.6.3\core-3.6.3.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\electronwill\night-config\toml\3.6.3\toml-3.6.3.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\jline\jline\3.12.1\jline-3.12.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\maven\maven-artifact\3.6.3\maven-artifact-3.6.3.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\jodah\typetools\0.8.3\typetools-0.8.3.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.15.0\log4j-api-2.15.0.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.15.0\log4j-core-2.15.0.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-slf4j18-impl\2.15.0\log4j-slf4j18-impl-2.15.0.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecrell\terminalconsoleappender\1.2.0\terminalconsoleappender-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.4\jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\spongepowered\mixin\0.8.4\mixin-0.8.4.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\minecraftforge\nashorn-core-compat\15.1.1.1\nashorn-core-compat-15.1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\patchy\1.3.9\patchy-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.4.0\jna-4.4.0.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j\66.1\icu4j-66.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\javabridge\1.0.22\javabridge-1.0.22.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.1.25.Final\netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\21.0\guava-21.0.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\commons-io-2.5.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\brigadier\1.0.17\brigadier-1.0.17.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\datafixerupper\4.0.26\datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\2.1.28\authlib-2.1.28.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\8.2.1\fastutil-8.2.1.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\3.2.2\lwjgl-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-jemalloc\3.2.2\lwjgl-jemalloc-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-openal\3.2.2\lwjgl-openal-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-opengl\3.2.2\lwjgl-opengl-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-glfw\3.2.2\lwjgl-glfw-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-stb\3.2.2\lwjgl-stb-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-tinyfd\3.2.2\lwjgl-tinyfd-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\text2speech\1.11.3\text2speech-1.11.3.jar;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.16.5-forge-36.2.39\1.16.5-forge-36.2.39.jar -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-exports=java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns=java.naming --add-opens=java.base/java.util.jar=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher --username <username> --version 1.16.5-forge-36.2.39 --gameDir C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft --assetsDir C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets --assetIndex 1.16 --uuid <uuid> --accessToken <token> --userType msa --versionType release --launchTarget fmlclient --fml.forgeVersion 36.2.39 --fml.mcVersion 1.16.5 --fml.forgeGroup net.minecraftforge --fml.mcpVersion 20210115.111550
```

I pasted the arguments in the code and expected it to run with no errors but I got an error.
Error: Could not find or load main class  -Dminecraft.launcher.version=2.6.16
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  -Dminecraft.launcher.version=2.6.16

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.